# Time pseudotype instead of ISO8601 when using group operator

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm getting started with RethinkDB and I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on with some queries I'm running.

The problem is querying objects with date time types from a NodeJS app  **(using the rethinkdbdash driver)** which exposes a JSON API. If I query my objects individually like:

```
db.table('apples').max('timestamp');
```

I get JavaScript Dates for timestamp fields, while if I run a group by operator in the query like in:

```
db.table('apples').group('type').max('timestamp');
```

I get date time pseudotypes (I think this is the correct name) for the same timestamp fields instead. Something like:

```
{
  "$reql_type$": "TIME",
  "epoch_time": 1423077646.772,
  "timezone": "-07:00"
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour? What is the logic behind it?

I would like to return serialized iso8601 dates in my JSON and not this data type to make parsing transparent to clients.

thanks,

---

**UPDATE**
This was a known issue for versions prior to 2.2.7. [Fixed here](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash/commit/0810454a97236dce59dbc6024511cdfea831b23a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug in rethinkdbdash.  The server always sends times to the clients as pseudotypes (the object with the `$reql_type$` field), and the clients are responsible for turning the pseudotypes into native time objects (since drivers in different languages have to do that differently).  I'd open a bug at https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash/issues .

I would guess the source of the bug is that `group` returns a `GROUPED_DATA` pseudotype and rethinkdbdash isn't correctly converting pseudotypes that are inside of other pseudotypes.  If you run `db.table('apples').group('type').max('timestamp').ungroup()`, that might fix the problem for this query until the driver is patched.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @mlucy, ungrouping does indeed fix the problem in this specific case. I'll bring it up to the rethinkdbdash people. Thanks again.